# How to join 2 tables without an ON clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the `SUM(column_a)` from two different tables, and get their difference. I am using MySQL.

`Table A's sum = 1234`

`Table B's sum = 4001`

I'm not sure what to put in my `ON` clause:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(a.column1) AS table_a_sum,
  SUM(b.column1) AS table_b_sum,
  SUM(a.column1) - SUM(b.column1) AS difference
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b
ON ??????
```

Comment: as a side note the `on` clause doesn't have to use properties of the tables you can have `select * from tableA inner join tableB on 1=1` and will get the same thing as a cross join

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A join without condition is a cross join.  A cross join repeats each row for the left hand table for each row in the right hand table:

```
FROM table_a a
CROSS JOIN table_b b
```

Note that in MySQL, `cross join` / `join` / `inner join` are identical.  So you could write:

```
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b
```

As long as you omit the `on` clause, this will work as a cross join.

If you'd like to sum two columns from two tables, a cross join would not work because it repeats rows.  You'd get highly inflated numbers.  For sums, a better approach uses subqueries, per @sgeddes answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one option using subqueries -- there are several ways to do this:

```
SELECT 
  table_a_sum,
  table_b_sum,
  table_a_sum - table_b_sum AS difference
FROM 
    (SELECT SUM(column1) table_a_sum FROM table_a) a,
    (SELECT SUM(column1) table_b_sum FROM table_b) b
```

Comment: +1 On re-reading, this is actually what the OP intends to do.

Answer (score 1):

You want to summarize first and then do the calculations:

```
select a.suma, b.sumb, a.suma - b.sumb
from (select sum(a.column1) as suma from tablea) a cross join
     (select sum(b.column1) as sumb from tableb) b
```

Doing the `cross join` between the tables will generate a cartesian product that will mess up your sums.