# Select * from to_tsvector - joining tables

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I want to set the `to_tsvector` language (e.g.: 'French') so it uses the proper dictionary when rendering the FTS vector.

Table messages has a `locale_id` column, which is on the `locales` table. Which I then need to join the `locales` table to the `languages` table on locale_id to get the actual language name. But I'm getting an ambiguous `;` error:

```
select * from to_tsvector(t3.language, t1.message) 
inner join message as t1 
inner join locales as t2 on (t1.locale_id = t2.id) 
inner join languages as t3 on (t2.language_id = t3.id);
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";" LINE 1: ....id)
>
> inner join languages as t3 on (t2.language_id = t3.id);

Answer (score 1):

newer code:

```
select to_tsvector(t3.language, t1.message) 
from message as t1 
inner join locales as t2 on (t1.locale_id = t2.id) 
inner join languages as t3 on (t2.language_id = t3.id);
```

original fix:

```
select * from to_tsvector(t3.language, t1.message) 
inner join message as t1 on 1 = 1 /* an ON join criteria is mandatory here even if you are doing an implicit cross join */
inner join locales as t2 on (t1.locale_id = t2.id) 
inner join languages as t3 on (t2.language_id = t3.id);
```

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508142/how-to-join-2-tables-without-an-on-clause I thought that wasn't needed

Comment: Now error `missing FROM-clause entry for table "t3"`

Comment: @Growler perhaps in MySQL, but not in most SQL dialects.  If you say INNER JOIN, you'll need an ON clause.  (Or use CROSS JOIN)

Comment: @Growler I see, I think you probably shouldn't be treating to_tsvector as a table.

Comment: `select from to_tsvector` gives the output of the vector though which is a good way to test some inputs. How else would you do it?

Comment: @Growler I recommend setting up a test case with simple sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and then what output you want.